# How to convert int to hex and write hex to file?

Tags: python, type-conversion, int, hex, python-2.x

I want to do the following in Python 2.7.13:

- Convert int-value to hex (`58829405413336430` should become `d101085402656e`)
- Add a "payload" (Simple string like c1234) to the created hex
- Write **pure** hex to a file

My code currently looks like this:

```
mime=58829405413336430
payload="c9999"

fw_file=open('testhex', 'wb')
fw_file.write("%x" % mime)
fw_file.write(str(payload).encode("hex"))
fw_file.close()
```

And I get the following file (Using `xxd` on Debian):

```
xxd HACKEDTOGETHER
00000000: 6431 3031 3038 3534 3032 3635 3665 3633  d101085402656e63
00000010: 3339 3339 3339 3339                      39393939
```

which is **not** what i need. I need a file that looks like this:

```
xxd WORKING
00000000: d101 0854 0265 6e63 3939 3939            ...T.enc9999
```

My understanding is the following:

`"%x" % mime` converted my int to hex, but it was written as a String. `encode` did it correctly, but that doesn't work with integers. How can I circumvent this behavior and write "pure" hex to my file? If it is not possible to do it in Python 2 i can also use Python 3.

As this is my first question on StackOverflow please tell me if I should do anything different.

Comment: hexadecimal is only a way of *representing* an integer number. So it is not a "conversion"

Answer (score 2):

Part of the problem is that the result of `"%x" % mime` is a string of the pairs of hexadecimal *characters* — `"d101085402656e"`in this case — which represents the value of the integer `mime` in that format, so that's what is being written to the file. However what's needed are the actual byte values that comprise the integer itself.

In Python 3, this could be easily solved by instead using a built-in method called [`to_bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) that was added to the `int` type in that version, but in Python 2.x it has to be done another way.

There's similar issue due to your use of `str(payload).encode("hex")` which is also returning a hexadecimal string representation — not the actual byte values of each the characters already in `payload`, which is what is needed. Fortunately in this case what needs to be can be easily accomplished by using the built-in [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray) class Python 2.x has.

Below a version I wrote of a function posted as part of an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44803688/355230) to a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44803084/convert-2-integers-to-hex-byte-array) that can deal with the issue with the `mime` value.

Following that function definition is code showing how to use it in this case, along with the `bytearray` class, to get the proper binary data written to the file.

```
def int_to_bytes(n, minlen=0):
    """ Convert integer to bytearray with optional minimum length. 
    """
    if n > 0:
        arr = []
        while n:
            n, rem = n >> 8, n & 0xff
            arr.append(rem)
        b = bytearray(reversed(arr))
    elif n == 0:
        b = bytearray(b'\x00')
    else:
        raise ValueError('Only non-negative values supported')

    if minlen > 0 and len(b) < minlen: # zero padding needed?
        b = (minlen-len(b)) * '\x00' + b
    return b

mime = 58829405413336430
payload = 'c9999'

with open('testhex', 'wb') as fw_file:
    fw_file.write(int_to_bytes(mime))
    fw_file.write(bytearray(payload))
```

Here's a hex dump of contents of the `testhex` file it produced (with Python 2.7.15):

```
00000000h: D1 01 08 54 02 65 6E 63 39 39 39 39             ; Ñ..T.enc9999
```

Comment: I don't think they wanted the payload converted to ASCII hex. And you could replace `divmod(n, 256)` with `n>>8, n&0xff`.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks for the heads-up on the payload issue. I updated my answer accordingly, but I left the `divmod()` in because although what you say seems reasonable, a while ago I actual timed the difference and surprisingly it was faster.

Comment: I just timed it in 3.6 and I get the opposite result: `divmod` is 0.13, and `>> &` is 0.10.

Comment: @Mark: Can't argue with that...answer further updated. Thanks again for the insight. I think I was confusing the use of `divmod()` with the use of another built-in (`math.hypot()` which isn't relevant here).